# Django Template: Dynamic template variable inside another variable

Tags: django, for-loop, variables, django-templates

I hope this makes sense... I am building a crypto asset list page (easy); however, in the {% for %} loop I would like to include a variable inside a variable. Showing the code will make more sense:

**Tempalte.html**

```
{% for crypto_asset in objects__list_cryptoAssets %}
   <tr role="row" class="body-row">
      <td role="cell">{{ api_external_prices.bitcoin.usd }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So the {% for %} loop grabs all the crypto assets and then I can use Django template {{ asset_class.slug }} to grab all slugs... nothing exceptional here. This variable {{ api_external_prices.bitcoin.usd }} grabs external USD prices for Bitcoin, {{ api_external_prices.bitcoin.eur }} prices in EUR, and so forth... nothing exceptional here either.

Here is where the question comes :: the idea would be to have something like **{{ api_external_prices.{{ asset_class.slug }}.usd }}**... so each crypto would have its own price FX fetched correctly. **Is it possible to have a variable *inside* a variable?**

Answer (score 1):

They are several ways you can implement this:

### Template filters

You can create a template filter `api_external_prices` that takes `asset_class` and the crypto type as parameters and returns the value.

The syntax would be something link this, where `api_external_prices` is the name of the template filter:

```
{{ asset_class|api_external_prices:"usd" }}
```

See here for more info about this feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

### Methods

Another approach would be to have `api_external_prices` as method on your `asset_class` object, which returns an object that has a `usd` property. `api_external_prices` here can just be a wrapper that calls a central module/function, but this would make it much easier to use it in templates.

```
{{ asset_class.api_external_prices.usd }}
```

The first approach is similar to what you are asking, but personally I would prefer to use the 2nd approach, because it saves you from introducing as template filter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would love to understand more about the implementation of the second method... I will put the remaining code to understand how you would tackle method 2

Comment: hmm. I thought all the data was coming from models, but now I see that you are fetching some of it in the view. That will make it difficult to apply any of the two solutions.

Comment: A third approach would be to create a data structure in the view that let's you access everything you need in the template. I would just try to map everything into a big list of nested dicts. e.g. the top dict representing the crypt assets and then each having a dict of prices by unit.